# QIDITECH Dual Extruder and PETG

Tags: filament, petg

I have just received my QIDITECH printer, I've have ABS, PLA and two reals of PETG.  I printed a sample using the clear PETG and this worked find, I didn't have to change any of the default settings.

Today I've tried three times to print a simple model using the black real of PETG.  I've created which is essentially just a rectangle, but after a few minutes the extruder starts to drag around filament.

What can I do?  The filament is loaded ok, and it starts out ok, but very quickly messes up.

Comment: This happens if the nozzle is too close to the bed. PETG likes to be *laid* down, not *squidged* down (like PLA). Try increasing your first layer height. I typically use 0.3mm for PLA and 0.35mm for PETG. Black (and white) PETG generally has more additives then coloured (or clear) PETG, and this is probably what is causing a difference in handling.

Comment: @Mick, thank you, I'm giving it a try now, its very difficult to just .05 of a mm.

Comment: @Mick, obviously I still haven't set it correctly, worse than ever, now it dragged up more.

Comment: I'm now up to 6 attempts at printing with BLACK PETG, every attempt ends with it dragging up...yet I've ensure the plate has glue on it before printing, I've tried several adjustments on the levelling of the bed and distance to extruders.  I'm thinking its something to do with the PETG filament itself, I have printing with a WHITE PETG successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a while back I created this post, since then I've have numerous problems / learning curves and now I'm very pleased to say I have a printer that prints perfectly and is set-up correctly.

I must say that the support from QidiTech is first class and during my journey I was sent a new extruder assembly, new extruders and also new print matts, all completely free and covered by the warranty.

I have now printed numerous models successfully.

Comment: What WAS the error?! As it is: not an answer.

Comment: It great that you've fixed your printer. How did you resolve your issue? Was it by replacing the extruder? If so, then do you know what was wrong with the original extruder? If you could provide more details about the actual issue and solution, it might help someone else, and save a call to the support desk.

Comment: In the end it was a combination of several things, getting the distance correct between the extruder and the bed, still a bit of a black art...most of the videos lack important information like how much friction should there be between the levelling card and the extruder...I opted for quite tight but still moveable.  Cleaning the extruders making sure there were no blockages and getting the temperates right for the material for both the bed and the extruders.